# Start and stop GCE instances using bash or python script

Tags: python, bash, google-compute-engine

I have GCE instance setup and already being used. With some services setup and running. I need to be able to stop it and start it with bash or python scripts in a cron job as I won't it to be running only at specific times and days. Is this possible? Also would be nice if I could make a snapshot and restore from it.

Comment: See [snapshot docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#snapshots) for info on creating and using snapshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use command line ([gcloud tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start)) or [Google Compute API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/start) to start or stop the instances. You can implement any of the above method in your script.

Moreover, you can take a look at [Preemptible](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) instances which are recently announced. These instances runs on a periodic basis and are very suitable for jobs like batch processing.